# Updating Pivot Table Filters with vba

Tags: excel, vba

Picture 1:

[image]

To update the filter (Picture 1, 1st pt) the vba code as below works fine and updates to the single chosen month as spelled in the range ("Y2") in this case.

```
.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Month").ClearAllFilters
.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Month").CurrentPage = Range("Y2").Value
```

However, the pivot table next to it (Picture 1, pt on the right), I need to update with a date range and when I use the code as below I get "application or object defined error"

```
.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Month").ClearAllFilters
.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Month").PivotFilters.Add _
    Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=Range("Y1").Value, Value2:=Range("Y2").Value
```

---

When I change the pivot table as below; get the "Month" field out of filter but apply it to columns, as below picture

Picture 2:

[image]

Then the below code works just fine.

```
.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Month").ClearAllFilters
.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Month").PivotFilters.Add _ 
    Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=Range("Y1").Value, Value2:=Range("Y2").Value
```

However, since I can't change the pivot table in the template, I need to update the pivot table in the template as the 1st picture above (the second pivot table on the right) with a date range and I am stuck